# keras.models.load_model takes too long to import

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I have a python project where I import keras.models.load_model:

```py
from keras.models import load_model
```

This causes my project to launch in 3 to 4 seconds, how can I decrease the import time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the benchmarks from this [article](https://towardsdatascience.com/tensorflow-performance-loading-models-fb2d0dc340a3), the format in which you save your weights affects how fast your model instantiates and loads saved weights.

It seems that the`.h5` format is faster than the `SavedModel` format. However, if speed is really paramount to the function of your project then you may want to look at taking one of these steps, although it definitely involves some work:

1. [Reducing the precision of your model](https://www.tensorflow.org/model_optimization/guide/quantization/post_training)
2. [Reducing your model size by pruning weights](https://www.tensorflow.org/model_optimization/guide/pruning)
3. Using [TensorFlow lite](https://www.tensorflow.org/lite) (however note that some models aren't supported)

Answer (score 0):

Agree with @evantkchong.

`h5` format is a light-weight alternative to SavedModel. As it is light weight, it loads faster than `SavedModel` or `tf` format. However, there are limitations that are important to consider.

If your model is simple, saving in `h5` format and loading it is better option. But, if you have complex custom model, then `SavedModel`/`tf` format is better.

The following is from [Tensorflow website](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/keras/save_and_serialize#limitations)

> - External losses & metrics added via model.add_loss() &
>   model.add_metric() are not saved (unlike SavedModel). If you have such
>   losses & metrics on your model and you want to resume training, you
>   need to add these losses back yourself after loading the model. Note
>   that this does not apply to losses/metrics created inside layers via
>   self.add_loss() & self.add_metric(). As long as the layer gets loaded,
>   these losses & metrics are kept, since they are part of the call
>   method of the layer.
> - The computation graph of custom objects such as
>   custom layers is not included in the saved file. At loading time,
>   Keras will need access to the Python classes/functions of these
>   objects in order to reconstruct the model. See Custom objects.