# Any way to speed up the import time of load_model from keras.models?

Tags: python, keras, import

This question has been asked before in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70153446/keras-models-load-model-takes-too-long-to-import), however was not answered.

importing just this function takes almost 8 seconds on my system, whereas pandas for example takes less than a second to import.
This long of a wait time is absolutely unacceptable for my project, so I was wondering if there was any way to reduce the load time for this import.

```
import argv took: 0.0 sec
import pandas as pd took: 0.904778242111206 sec 
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler took: 1.4912829399108887 sec
from keras.models import load_model took: 7.647079229354858 sec
```

Comment: The time is not taken by keras.models, but the actual time is taken by tensorflow, because keras is an API which is built on the top of the tensorflow, so when you are loading this library first it loads tensorflow then this, so therefore it is taking too much time...

Comment: @MohammadAhmed Do you see any way of cutting down on the time then?